# Is TOTP or a timestamp encryption a better timestamp-based authentication token system?

Tags: encryption, authentication, one-time-password

Are there advantages to using [TOTP](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6238) over encrypting a timestamp with a shared secret, in cases where the readability or ease of typing the token are not important?

Comment: What is the sceneario you are targetting with that? The whole point of OTPs is ease of readability and typing.

Comment: Do you have / had a use-case where being able to extract the date from the code would be useful? (I know this question is quite old but it still sits here unanswered despite being quite answerable)